# Remove category attribute

Tags: attributes, sql, category-attribute

I inserted 2 category attributes using a module with the file `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` in a sql folder:

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'short_description', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Short Description',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'group'         => 'General',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false
));
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'static_block', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Brand',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'group'         => 'General',
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false
));

$this->endSetup();
```

How can I delete them now. I tried inserting this in the sql file, as suggested in other answers:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'short_description');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'static_block');
$installer->endSetup();
```

But nothing happens. Should I create another module?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a different upgrade script.
If the install script has the version `0.1.0` create the file `upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php` with this content:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'short_description');
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'static_block');
```

Then go to `config.xml` and change the `version` tag from `0.1.0` to `0.1.1`.

Clear the cache and refresh any page.

As a side node...don't use `$installer->startSetup();` in install/upgrade scripts that remove data. Calling it, disables the foreign key checks and you might end up with zombie data in your db.

Comment: This worked flawlesly on a version 1.9. But I have to do it on a magento version 1.5 too and it does not delete the field from backend. Deleted cache of course. Could it be a configuration that is blocking this? or something specific to 1.5?