# Delete category attribute from the database

Tags: magento2, database, attributes, eav, custom-attributes

In Magento 1 when I wanted to delete a category attribute, I could delete theattribute directly in the database in the `eav_attribute` table. I've done that many times without any problems.

Can I safely delete my custom category attributes this way also in **Magento 2**?

The table `eav_attribute` still exists, but there are also other tables with similar names. Would I also need to delete my attribute from other tables, or `eav_attribute` is enough? And is it safe to delete the attribute directly from the database in Magento 2?

Comment: yes you can delete directly from database same as magento 1. but would be prefer to use script to delete entry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. deleting the attribute from `eav_attribute` does not **created issue** .

It does not create an issue.

Answer (score -2):

If you try to delete category attribute programmatically then it will delete all attribute entry from all tables,

better then directly remove from table, you can follow below url

[Remove category attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67155/remove-category-attribute)

Or you can follow below code,

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$setup          = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$entityTypeId   = $setup->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeCode  = 'extra_activities';

$setup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
```

?>

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is for Magento 1, not for Magento 2.